Inverting position of MMU and cache inside a computer
I was thinking about a topic in my actual course and a question came to my mind.
What would happen if, at the hardware level, the position of the MMU and the cache were reversed inside a computer?
What hardware and software changes inside the kernel should be made?

Both positions are feasible: virtual address cache as well as physical address cache. Which do you propose to consider "standard", and which "reversed"?

Whichever way around you consider "standard" and "reversed", there is a whole book which explains the kernel aspects of different cache hardware: "UNIX(tm) Systems for Modern Architectures" by Curt Schimmel. The word "modern" is quaint in this context since it was published in 1994.

Many thanks @Pseudonym for your comment. I succeded in these days to retrieve a copy of the book and it has given me the answer to my original question. I never thought a book would contain such an accurate explanation of that topic.
